# Are there any downsides to using nanoid for primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I know that UUIDs and incrementing integers are often used for primary keys.
I'm thinking of nanoids instead because those are URL friendly without being guessable / brute-force scrapeable (like incrementing integers).

Would there be any reason not to use nanoids as primary keys in a database like Postgres? (For example: Maybe they drastically increase query time since they aren't ... aligned or something?)

https://github.com/ai/nanoid

Comment: Note that the publicly visible format or representation of keys/slugs/identifiers, such as in a URI, does not have to correspond to their raw DB PKs - for example, you can still use incrementing integer PKs in your database, but your frontend would use a library like hashids or really, any encryption algorithm that uses a small-block-size (e.g. a 64-bit block-size will give you a random-looking 16-char Base16 string for use in URIs).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most databases use incrementing id's because it's more efficient to insert a new value onto the end of a B-tree based index.

If you insert a new value into a random place in the middle of a B-tree, it may have to split the B-tree nonterminal node, and that could cause the node at the next higher level to split, and so on up to the top of the B-tree.

This also has a greater risk of causing fragmentation, which means the index takes more space for the same number of values.

Read https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/03/illustrating-primary-key-models-in-innodb-and-their-impact-on-disk-usage/ for a great visualization about the tradeoff between using an auto-increment versus UUID in a primary key.

That blog is about MySQL, but the same issue applies to any B-tree based data structure.

Comment: From (skimming) over the linked article, it seems the main performance difference is between using a UUID or an incrementing id. nanoid vs UUID won't make much of a difference.

Comment: Correct. I assume a nanoid is just as "random" as a UUID. That is, in both cases the next-allocated id is not guaranteed to be sorted greater than the last one. So both count as "random insertion order" and will have the same downside.

Comment: Well, do you suggest to use both int primary key and nanoid/uuid together? I mean B-tree based data structure needs auto-increment but we need url friendly identifier for data which is supplied by nanoid. What is the correct approach for you? @BillKarwin should you use id or tablename_id for auto-inc and just id for nanoid in same table?

Comment: IMO, I wouldn't use any nanoid. I'd use the numeric primary key as the identifier. You can start the integers at 1000000 if you want to obscure the fact that you don't have many records yet.

Comment: If you have already decided that you must use a nanoid as the human-facing identifier, then store it as a non-primary key attribute in the table.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for reply. The main reason is we want URL friendly without being guessable / brute-force scrapeable (like incrementing integers). Second needed is about primary key auto inc for indexing problems in tables, also inserting data in a correct order. I'm looking for a solution for my both problems. Nanoid helps me about my first need but I'm concerned about indexing. What if I add oid/rowid/table_id/smth column for integer pk-ai and id for nanoid? Is this a good choice or not? Thanks again.

Comment: @BillKarwin Actually I need three cases in big picture. 1) Without being guessable + brute-force scrapeable. 2) Indexing problem. 3) Inserting data in a correct order (uuid and random identifiers are inserting in a random order, but i have to insert new one to the end of table). Did you have any similar cases before?

Comment: Some people modify the standard UUID to ensure it is ordered by timestamp. This blog describes the technique: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/ But you'll have to investigate if that technique can be applied to the nanoid. I have no idea how the nanoid encodes its value, and it may not be possible to use this optimization technique.

Comment: At this point, I think you understand the tradeoffs. I can't answer for you which solution is best for your application. Now you get to choose. That's the job of being a professional software developer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245216/discussion-between-abdullah-ilgaz-and-bill-karwin).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a disadvantage to using nanoids, but they are often unnecessary. While UUIDs are long, they can be translated to a shorter format without losing entropy.

See the NPM package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/short-uuid).

Answer (score 0):

UUIDs are standardized by the Open Software Foundation (OSF) and described by the RFC 4122. That means that there will be far more chances for other tools to give you some perks around it.

Some examples:

- MongoDB has a special type to optimize the storage of UUIDs. Not only a NanoID string will take more space, but even the binary takes more bits (126 in Nano ID and 122 in UUID)
- Once saw a logging tool extracting the timestamp from the uids, can't remember which, but is is available

Also the long, non reduced version of UUIDs are very easy to identify visually. When the end user is a developer, it might help to understand the nature/source of the ID (like clearly not a database auto-increment key)